# "Google namespace cannot be found" within a loop, while it works for the rest of the function

Tags: asp.net, razor

I'm trying to make a webpage using asp.net, and need to use a loop to display several markers on a google map. The error description says that the google namespace cannot be found within the loop, while it works fine for the rest of the function. Does anyone know how to fix this? What I expected from this code is a map with markers at 46, -80; 47, -79; and 48, -78. Here's my code

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var mapProp = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(44, -80), //this google.maps call is fine
                zoom: 5,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //this one works too
            };
            var ClownMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

            {
                @for (var i=1; i < 4; i++){
                            var latitude = 45+i;
                            var longitude = -81+i;
                            var markerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude); //This line gives an error
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: markerPosition}); } //Error here too
                }
             marker.setMap(ClownMap);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:960px;height:600px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: whats the error it says?

Answer (score 1):

Razor thinks the code inside your for loop is c# since you did not specify otherwise.

Use the `<text>` element to specify it is not server code. `<text>` can be used to mix server code and plain text/markup/valid static html content.

```
@for (var i=1; i < 4; i++)
{
  <text>
       var latitude = 45 + i;
       var longitude = -81 + i;
       var markerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude); 
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: markerPosition });            
   </text>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not exiting the razer code, so your loop is expecting google namespace from your server sided code and not javascript.

try running a for loop in javascript instead.

that is remove the @ before your for loop starts, and make it look like this.

```
            for (var i=1; i < 4; i++){
                        var latitude = 45+i;
```